# MATLAB: Invisible figure handles behave differently on Windows and Linux?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I always thought that, in MATLAB, a graphic handle `X` whose property `HandleVisibility` is set to anything else than `on` will not show up when using `findobj(h)` or `get(h, 'Children')` with `h` being the parent of `X`. However, this seems to be true only under Windows and not under Linux. I am using MATLAB R2011b both on Debian 6.0.6 (squeeze) and Windows 7. If I run the following code under Windows:

```
figure;plot(randn(1,1000));
h = get(gcf, 'Children');
```

Then I get a single handle in `h`, which corresponds to the axes that contain my random plot. This is what I would expect. However, if I run exactly the same code in Linux, `h` contains an array of 10 handles. Indeed most of those handles are just UI elements, whose `HandleVisibility` property is set to `off`. For instance:

```
get(h(end), 'Type')   % returns: 'uitoolbar'
get(h(end), 'HandleVisibility') % returns 'off'
```

Is there a reason for this apparently inconsistent behavior? Can this be reproduced by others? In case it could be relevant, the Debian server that I am using runs Sun JAVA 1.6.0_26, which is not the default on Debian (openJDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce on either r2011a or r2012b, with Sun JAVA.

One workaround might be to filter based on visibility:

```
visibleChildren = findobj(get(h,'children'),'HandleVisibility','on')
```

Sounds like something specific to your install.